# Where to put scripts in MVC _layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I understand from reading advice on this site that scripts should go at the bottom of the _layout page. My problem is that I am not sure exactly where the 'bottom' is. Some people have said it is just before the  tag but that does not work for me. I have tried putting the script in many places but nowhere seems to work. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is my About page

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
     Put content here.
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    alert("Hello World");
  });
</script>
```

This is my _Layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  @* jQuery works if this line is here but not if it is at the bottom
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  *@
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="title">
        <h1>
          My MVC Application</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="logindisplay">
        @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
      </div>
      <div id="menucontainer">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
  </div>
  @* jQery does not work if the script is here! *@
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery file has to be included before first reference to jquery is found on the document. So, to solve this problem, i put jquery file in head section and all other script that are not used in views but in other script files are included before closing body tag

Comment: Hello Muhammad, many thanks for your clear explanation. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I think alternative of using a RenderSection for scripts is more clean.

Answer (score 13):

## Some Alternatives

It is absolutely possible to have your jquery at the end of your body tag. Ideally the only js you have in your head is `modernizr`, `html5shiv` or the like.

### Option 1

Put a `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` after the jQuery `<script...` element as the last line inside your body element. Then in any of your views you would use

```
@section scripts
{
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      // page specific js code here
    });
  </script>
}
```

### Option 2

Between your jQuery `script` element and the closing of your `body` element have a `script` element pointing to the relevant js file for the action/view in question:

```
<script 
  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/" + ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") + ".js")" 
  type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: So with option 1 should we be putting that within all of our views and our scripts go within those braces? So far that seems to be working but I thought the _layout.cshtml page was supposed to load all scripts and everything for you on every page with no addition work. No?

Comment: @DanielJackson you could put a `@RenderSection` in your `_layout.cshtml` and then in each page load only the required js libs that the page needs. You could also just load your minified and bundled js lib as a one off in your `_layout.cshtml`. There are many strategies for efficiently packaging js these days such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).