# Search Engine via AutoComplete did not work on _Layout.cshtml

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, autocomplete, search-engine

I just created a Search engine for user can filter a name of a product. At this time, I just make it in Search page. I'm wondering how to put `Search` function using Ajax method on **_Layout.cshtml**. I putted it already, *but it didn't show any suggestions.*

`Search` Ajax method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/Find",
                        data: "{ 'prefixText': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",

                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.value,
                                    value: item.value,
                                    id: item.id,
                                    name: item.name
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (even, ui) {
                    $("#hidSearch").val(ui.item.id);
                    //doSearch(ui.item.id);
                }
            });

            $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
                var id = $("#hidSearch").val();
                doSearch(id);
            });
        });
            function doSearch(id) {
            window.location.href = '/Home/Details?id=' + id;
        }
```

In `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<body>
        <div id="header">
        <h1><a href="/">ASP.NET MVC ADVENTURE CYCLES</a></h1>

          @using (Html.BeginForm())
      {
          <p>
              @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
              <input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch" />
              <input type="hidden" id="hidSearch" />
          </p>
      }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Find(string prefixText)
        {
            var suggestedProducts = from x in db.Products
                                    where x.Name.StartsWith(prefixText)
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        id = x.ProductID,
                                        value = x.Name + ", ",
                                        name = x.Name
                                    };

            var result = Json(suggestedProducts.Take(5).ToList());

            return result;
        }


        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(product);
        }
```

Any answers are welcome, thanks for reading my question!

Comment: Any errors if you take a look at a browser's Dev. Tools (e.g. Firebug)?

Comment: Put your controller action too. Also put browser reaction on this page(perhaps errors) should be useful.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi I edited it already!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any errors in a browser's Dev. Tools (like Firebug)?

Assuming that your JavaScript code is correct and does indeed perform a search correctly, check if that script comes after including the jQuery bundle (i.e. after `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`, etc.).

### **EDIT:**

You should try to debug the JavaScript in your browser (place breakpoints, look at the console, etc.). You can also try placing a breakpoint in your `/Home/Find` Controller method to see if it is receiving any requests at all.

Here's a sample on how I've made an autocomplete search-box some time ago:

```
$("#SearchObjects").autocomplete({

                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteObjects", "ObjectController")', 
                        type: "GET", 
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { Name: item.Name, ID: item.ID, value: item.Name };
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function(...){...}
                    })

                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var selecteditem = ui.item;
                    // What to do when the user selects something from the suggestions (...)
                }
            });
```

### **EDIT 2:**

I'd try something like:

```
(... _Layout.cshtml ...)

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<Your autocomplete script here> // (Preferably by including an external JS file)
```

**Related:**

- [Where to put scripts in MVC _layout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743993/where-to-put-scripts-in-mvc-layout-page)
- [jquery usage in asp.net mvc 4 _Layout.cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074382/jquery-usage-in-asp-net-mvc-4-layout-cshtml)

Comment: I checked it, it still didn't work. Is there another solution?

Comment: No errors in the debugger console? Is your controller method (/Home/Find) called?

Comment: In my Autocompletes' AJAX calls, I usually use a GET request.

Comment: I debugged it, it counted 5 variables. It work with in the `Search` page but in `_Layout.cshtml` it didn't.

Comment: `@Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.css") <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/kendo.all.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/kendo/2013.3.1119/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")`. Here is all the `Script` I use in `_Layout.cshtml`. Does it wrong?

Comment: See edit. I think you should only include your autocomplete script after including jQuery, Kendo, etc. Doesn't seem like you're doing it that way.

Comment: Great, you're welcome. What was the problem? If my answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as accepted. If it didn't, you should write your own answer and accept it.